# iText - get position of symbols combination

Tags: .net, itext

I can't find an example of how to use the iText API to get the positions (x,y) of specific combination of symbols (for example +< ) across a PDF document.
I can find position of rows or chunks with such symbols. But as far as i know, even if these symbols were as separate word in a document, it's not guarantee that it will be separate chunk.

Answer (score 5):

The class you're looking for is `RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy`.

You construct it using either a `String` object representing the regular expression, or feed it the regular expression directly.

You then apply it to a `PdfPage` using a `PdfCanvasProcessor` and then call `getResultantLocations`.

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC));

RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy extractionStrategy = new RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy(@"foobar");

IList<IPdfTextLocation> locationList = new List<IPdfTextLocation>();

PdfCanvasProcessor parser = new PdfCanvasProcessor(extractionStrategy);
parser.ProcessPageContent(pdfDoc.GetFirstPage());

extractionStrategy.GetResultantLocations(); // do something with them
```